# Javafx Slider increment with 10 on track click

Tags: java, javafx, slider

Like JSlider in javafx how we can increment with specific value like I want my slider knob should move by +10 on every right click on slider(anywhere on track ) and -10 on left click of slider(anywhere on track ). I am using following code but not getting the result

```
Slider betSlider = new Slider(0, 1000, 100);
betSlider.setMinorTickCount(0);
betSlider.setMajorTickUnit(10);
betSlider.setBlockIncrement(10);
betSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);

container.getChildren().add(betSlider);
betSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val, Number new_val) {
        betSlider.setValue(new_val.intValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#setBlockIncrement-double-

Comment: above is my code not sure why it is not working

Answer (score 1):

The main difficulty of this problem is that we don't have direct access to the track OnMouseClick logic ([SliderBehavior.trackPress](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/behavior/SliderBehavior.java#SliderBehavior.trackPress%28javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent%2Cdouble%29)).
This might be solved by creating custom slider with custom `SliderSkin` and `SliderBehavior`, but that sounds like an overkill.

It doesn't work as-is in your code snippet because when you click on the track the logic behind this action is to place the knob to the closest tick (once again, have a look at [SliderBehavior.trackPress](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/behavior/SliderBehavior.java#SliderBehavior.trackPress%28javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent%2Cdouble%29))

To solve this the following approach might be used (*Note, Java 8*):

```
private boolean valueChanged;
....
public void setupSlider() {
    Slider betSlider = new Slider(0, 100, 10);
    int blockIncrementStep = 10;
    betSlider.setMinorTickCount(0);
    betSlider.setMajorTickUnit(10);
    betSlider.setBlockIncrement(blockIncrementStep);
    betSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
    betSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
    container.getChildren().add(betSlider);
    betSlider.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!valueChanged) {
            valueChanged = true;
            if (newValue.intValue() > oldValue.intValue()) {
                betSlider.setValue(oldValue.intValue() + blockIncrementStep);
            } else {
                betSlider.setValue(oldValue.intValue() - blockIncrementStep);
            }
        }
    });
    betSlider.setOnMouseClicked(event -> valueChanged = false);
}
```

Each time `betSlider.setValue` method is called - `betSlider.valueProperty().changed` method is triggered as well. And only when there are no more changes `setOnMouseClicked` is triggered. Hence, we can simply track if the value has been already changed after a click on a track and if not - change it manually.