# JavaFX slider - only respond to drag (ignore track click)

Tags: java, javafx

I would like the slider only to respond to the user dragging the slider and always ignoring when the user clicks on the track.

This is my sample code:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Slider slider = new Slider();

        slider.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                event.getTarget();
                //Do something here based on target...?
                event.consume();

            }
        });

        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        flowPane.getChildren().add(slider);

        var scene = new Scene(flowPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

I have tried working around with the addEventHandler and getting the target (track or thumb) but not sure what to do.

EDIT: Another solution may be only changing the value by one when clicking the track.

SECOND EDIT: Below is my latest try and it prints exactly what I want in the console, so all is fine, except for the fact (and most important) that the slider reacts very slow so it is not a usable solution:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private boolean valueChanged;
    int blockIncrementStep = 1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setMin(0);
        slider.setMax(255);
        slider.setBlockIncrement(blockIncrementStep);

        slider.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {

            valueChanged = false;
            System.out.println((int) slider.getValue());

        });

        slider.setOnMouseClicked(event -> valueChanged = false);

        slider.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (!valueChanged) {

                valueChanged = true;

                if (newValue.intValue() > oldValue.intValue()) {

                    slider.setValue(oldValue.intValue() + blockIncrementStep);
                    System.out.println(oldValue.intValue() + blockIncrementStep);
                    
                } else {

                    slider.setValue(oldValue.intValue() - blockIncrementStep);
                    System.out.println(oldValue.intValue() - blockIncrementStep);
                    
                }
            } else {

            }
        });

        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        flowPane.getChildren().add(slider);

        var scene = new Scene(flowPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
    
}
```

I had to add "valueChanged = false" to setOnMouseDragged or else it would not function properly when the slider was dragged to the min and max of the slider.

THIRD EDIT:

I think I got an working example now:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private boolean valueChanged;
    int blockIncrementStep = 1;
    Slider slider;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        slider = new Slider();
        slider.setMin(0);
        slider.setMax(255);
        slider.setBlockIncrement(blockIncrementStep);

        slider.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {

            getSliderValue();

        });

        slider.setOnMouseClicked(event -> valueChanged = false);

        slider.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (newValue.intValue() == 255 || oldValue.intValue() == 255 || newValue.intValue() == 0 || oldValue.intValue() == 0) {

                valueChanged = false;

            }

        });

        slider.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (!valueChanged) {

                valueChanged = true;

                if (newValue.intValue() > oldValue.intValue()) {

                    slider.setValue(oldValue.intValue() + blockIncrementStep);
                    getSliderValue();

                } else {

                    slider.setValue(oldValue.intValue() - blockIncrementStep);
                    getSliderValue();

                }
            }

        });

        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        flowPane.getChildren().add(slider);

        var scene = new Scene(flowPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    private void getSliderValue() {

        System.out.println((int) slider.getValue());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch();

    }

}
```

Feel free to post an answer if you got a better solution. Especially a easier solution as I have many sliders in my app :)

Regards

Comment: The `blockIncrement` property is "The amount by which to adjust the slider if the track of the slider is clicked."

Comment: It is not working. I think there is a typo in the documentation. This is in the in-depth-documentation: This is used when manipulating the slider position using _keys_

Comment: Ah, I see; you want something like a _page_ adjustment, as happens in a `ScrollBar`; one approach is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50209540/230513).

Comment: Yes, that may be a solution, except that the drag-function is lost - I also want the slider-value to change when the user clicks and drags the thumb.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), which is preferable to posting answers inside the question.

Comment: Your working example doesn't seem to do what the question asks: "ignore track click". The user can still click on the track in the example you provided and the slider will react. I wonder a bit if this is an [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info) and you may not want to actually ignore the track click.

Comment: Yes, I guess that was a classic x-y-problem. I did not see my own solutions as a proper answer, I think it was too complicated so I did not want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

> (ignore track click)

If you look at the [CSS guide for JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#slider), the substructure for a slider consists of "axis, track, thumb".

If you only want the user to be able to click on the thumb in the slider, you can [add an event filter](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter(javafx.event.EventType,javafx.event.EventHandler)) to the slider and filter out all mouse events that don't relate to the thumb.  You can find the thumb node via a [lookup](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup(java.lang.String)).

Here is an example:

```
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class BlockedSlider extends Slider {
    public BlockedSlider(double min, double max, double value, double increment) {
        super(min, max, value);
        setMajorTickUnit(increment);
        setMinorTickCount(0);
        setBlockIncrement(increment);
        setShowTickMarks(true);
        setSnapToTicks(true);
        addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
            Node thumb = lookup(".thumb");
            if (thumb != event.getTarget()) {
                event.consume();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The example also adds some other settings to customize the slider, which makes it easier to see the operation and what it is doing.  You can adjust those customizations to fit your application requirements.

The example still allows keyboard input to change the slider value, so it doesn't "only respond to drag".  The slider value can also be set in code, without user interaction, and the slider will still respond to that.

Here is an example of using the example `BlockedSlider` class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BlockedSliderApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Slider slider = new BlockedSlider(1, 5, 3, 1);
        slider.valueProperty().addListener(o -> {
            if (!slider.isValueChanging()) {
                System.out.println("Slider value: " + slider.getValue());
            }
        });

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(slider);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        var scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        slider.setValue(1.8);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd be hesitant about disabling the default ability to click on the track to update the slider value.  I find it makes the slider work differently than other slider controls I have used.  I would look to other potential solutions, retaining standard functionality, to implement the UI.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking/hoping for! Nice and simple and very nice making a new subclass with the new behavior. It may seem odd I want to disable the track click but I think that is always needed when the slider will function as a fader in a sound-mixing or light-mixing app (level-control), then you never want the fader to jump if the user by a mistake touches the track.

Comment: @droid the mixing desk fader use-case for this makes total sense, thanks for explaining it.